# MySQL workbench can not get running, beginner questiom

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Im studying some SQL in college at the moment, on campus we use MySQL workbench, So i decided to download the software on my personal machine to practice some queries on.

Im a total beginner in this so apologies if this isnt making scene. Well when i go to start new connection the way we do in college i get a error message when i test it. Ive attached a screen shot, does any one know what im doing wrong? is there another piece of software i need to install?

[image]

Comment: Is your mysqld service started?

Answer (score 1):

You might not give correct credentials to connect to MySQL server. Give correct username, password,hostname and port.